# How to use foreach in foreach loop iin node js can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I have Two tables and table1 have multile ids of images and this images are stored  in tabel 2 i am using for loop but it give me can't sent header error due to use of for loop.so what can i do please help 
I am using mongo db

Comment: For starters, please show your code.

Comment: https://imgsafe.org/image/e4972a7586

Comment: @Teemu Please check the image

Comment: We dont want to give effort by retyping your code from your image. Post your code here

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the 'async' NPM. Install the npm first with,

```
npm install async --save
```

Then use it in your code as follows,

```
const async = require('async');

async.forEach(Table1Ids, function (item, callback){ 
    console.log(item); // print the id or object

    table2.findOne({id: item.id}, function(err, doc){
        if(err){
            callback(err)
        }else if (doc){
            //Image fetch success. Use the doc here.
            callback();
        }else {
            callback();
        }
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log('iterating done');
    //You can respond from here.
});
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: It works but give only one id image data and also give me can't sent header

https://imgsafe.org/image/e5fed40224

Comment: I saw your code image in comments section. You are trying to respond multiple times for a single request. That's not possible.

Comment: Try this,

    1. Find the image id's and send it to the client.
    2. From the client you can loop the array of image id's and put a separate request for each of them.

Comment: can i do this for examle in php we use sql query where in $varaiblae and in $varaib;e have multiple ids with comma seprated.
can this implement in node wiith mongo db

Comment: Yes it can be done. This is actually a Node and Mongo DB code.